# what does this "\\1" mean in php?

Tags: php

I'm learning **PHP** language , and I faced this line in some **PHP** script :

```
function cc($re,$val){
return preg_replace( '/('. $re . ')/ei ,
'strtolower("\\1")',
$value 
);
 }
```

so what does this symbol mean '//1' in **strtolwer function** 
I'm not asking for regex !!! , Im asking for /1 means in **php** ?

Comment: Use this `return preg_replace_callback( '/('.preg_quote($re,'/').')/i',function($match){
        return strtolower($match[1]);
    }, $val);`  [Sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/2a1ab0de50054639c433482e90b450b10ff3431c) It's about as close as you can get with modern PHP. The `e` modifier is a well known security vulnerability, hence it's removal from PHP.

Answer (score 2):

The backslash is an [escape character](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.escape.php), it's used to escape the proceeding backslash. What that means is that it translates `\\1` to `\1`, and `\1` is a reference to the output of the preg_replace. Your code had some errors, I cleaned it up:

```
function cc($re,$val){
    return preg_replace( '/('.$re.')/ei' ,'strtolower("\\1")',$val);
}
```

Keep in mind that this won't work in newer versions of PHP, because in newer versions of PHP, the /e modifier is no longer supported, and we're encouraged to use [preg_replace_callback()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php) instead, like so:

```
function cc($re,$val){
    return preg_replace_callback( '/('.$re.')/i' ,function($matches){
        return strtolower($matches[1]);
    },$val);
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot , but I need to know what this /1 mean , ??

Comment: @drlearrn003 `\\1` will be translated in the replacement callback string to the regular expression pattern of `\1` which is synonymous with using `$1` representing "the first group" in the pattern with parenthesis. So pattern `(\w)\w`,  with a value of `AB`, using `\1` will match `A` https://3v4l.org/CT4Ib I provided an example of either and an updated method for use with `preg_replace_callback` and PHP 5.3+

Comment: It is important to note, using `preg_eplace` with a callback string and without the `e` modifier, will not yield the desired results.  Using `cc('\w', 'AB')` the code in your answer will return `strtolower("A")strtolower("B")` instead of the desired `ab`;  In addition using `preg_replace_callback('/('.$re.')i/','strtolower("\\1")',$val)` will result in an error. Example: https://3v4l.org/di9ZQ

Comment: @fyrye Good point. I amended my answer to include a snippet using preg_replace_callback().

Comment: Well it may work in this case I am sure you mean `$matches[1]` and not `$matches[0]` one is the first capture group, the other is the whole match.  Me just being 'nit-picky' .. lol

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix ah yes, exactly. Changed.

Comment: It would have been OK in this case as the whole match was the capture group.  But I thought I should mention it.